# Sharing an object between two classes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm developing an app for OS X and I got stuck with a problem.

The structure of the app is :

- AppDelegate: where the main actions take place from MainMenu.xib. It's also where the main window is created.
- SettingsWindowController: where a settings window is defined with interface from SettingsWindow.xib.
- I created a protocol SettingsWindowProtocol to delegate those two classes.
- I created one more class dbHandler which is initialized as an obj `dbh` in AppDelegate.
- In SettingsWindowProtocol I created a method to send the object but after I call this method in SettingsWindowControl the object is null.

The question is how I share in two different classes the same object ?

A few blocks of code related to question:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "dbHandler.h"    

...

@property (retain) dbHandler *dbh;
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <SettingsWindowControllerProtocol>

-(dbHandler*)sendDBobject;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
...
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{   
    dbh = [[dbHandler alloc]init];
    ...
}

- (IBAction)settingsButton:(id)sender {
    if(!settingsWindowController){
        settingsWindowController = [[SettingsWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SettingsWindow"];
    }

    [settingsWindowController showWindow:self];
    settingsWindowController.delegate = self;
}

-(dbHandler*)sendDBobject{
    return dbh;
}
```

SettingsWindowController.h :

```
#import "dbHandler.h"

@protocol SettingsWindowControllerProtocol<NSObject>
    -(dbHandler*)sendDBobject;
@end

@interface SettingsWindowController : NSWindowController

@property (assign) id<SettingsWindowControllerProtocol> delegate;

@property (retain) dbHandler* dbh;

@end
```

SettingsWindowController.m:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    dbh = [delegate sendDBobject];
    [super windowDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"settings string returned: %@",[dbh returnString]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your app delegate from anywhere in your app via the `NSApp delegate` method. So to get the `dbh` object, you would just do something like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [NSApp delegate];
dbh = appDelegate.dbh;
```

Comment: Good insight, but please use `NSApp`, since this is OS X not iOS.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the quick replay. But I'm developing for osX so instead of UIApplication I used NSApplication like this :     
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
dbh = appDelegate.dbh;
And I got a warning:
 Initializing 'AppDelegate *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<NSApplicationDelegate>'

Comment: Oh great is working now but can you explain me why in this way is working and throw the method from protocol is not working ? what if initializations of dbHandler it wouldn't be in the AppDelegate

Comment: @user1792771 A protocol just defines a shared interface that objects conforming to that protocol are expected to implement. It doesn't somehow give you global access to any property in other objects conforming to the protocol. If you want to initialize the dbHandler from somewhere other than the app delegate you can do that, but I would still recommend storing the result in the app delegate, since that is the one object that is always easy to access from elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Using the Application delegate as some kind of general storage space and switch for an application is just being lazy. It isn't recommended by anyone I know. I still cringe when I see people calling down into the app delegate for the managed object context rather than just passing it up the stack.

Comment: @Abizern Your comment is perfectly valid, and I once cringed, too. However, being a full-time developer, it's not unusual to write 2-3 throwable prototypes in a single day, and it's so damn convenient to use this approach and static methods, too!

Comment: @Abizern It might be helpful if you could enumerate some of the advantages of the approach you are suggesting. Perhaps submit another answer showing how you would do it and explain why it's better than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've made some bad design choices in your application. Not only are you calling down to the app delegate to get the dbh, but you also seem to have a method there that responds to an action message (`settingsButton:`). Generally, the app delegate is there to be the application's delegate - responding to delegate methods. It's a sign of an inexperienced developer when it does more than that; I frequently see new developers use the app delegate as a convenient singleton object where they can stash data or methods instead of doing it in a more object oriented fashion.

It doesn't help that the Xcode application template initialises the Core Data Stack in the AppDelegate, and many tutorials use the delegate as storage because it keeps the project focussed on the subject of the tutorial rather than increasing complexity by doing things the way they would be done in the real world.

Remember, you want the delegate to do as little as possible. So let the app delegate set up the bare minimum number of objects, hook them up together and get out of the way.

In your case I see two things that you could be doing better. Rather than setting up a protocol to call down to your app delegate to get an object, just send it up the stack to the view controller. And secondly, you have an action method in your application delegate which would be better off in a view controller instead. Since I don't want to get too much into the second, and as your question is about sharing objects; here's how to pass the object up the stack without using a protocol.

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // This is okay, although it's preferable to be explicit with properties
    self.dbh = [[dbHandler alloc] init];
    ... 
}

- (IBAction)settingsButton:(id)sender {
    if(!self.settingsWindowController){
        self.settingsWindowController = [[SettingsWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SettingsWindow"];

        // It already has a property for the dbh, just give it to it
        self.settingsWindowController.dbh = self.dbh;
    }

    [self.settingsWindowController showWindow:self];
    self.settingsWindowController.delegate = self;
}

// And you don't need this, or the protocol
//-(dbHandler*)sendDBobject{
//    return dbh;
//}
```

Why is this better? There is a principle of "tell, don't ask". In this case you are telling the settings view controller what the dbh is, not making it ask some other object. Also, you are no longer coupled to an App delegate which conforms to a protocol, which means the controller is less coupled to other objects in your app. Imagine you were to unit test your settings view controller, it's so much easier to just give it the object it wants, rather than setting up the infrastructure for it to ask for things.

Comment: So I guess the key advantage is decoupling other objects from the app delegate. I appreciate you taking the time to provide such a detailed explanation. Thanks.

Comment: It's also a pattern we see a lot already in things like navigation controllers and Storyboard segues -> Information is __passed up__ the stack through properties, and information and actions __passed down__ the stack through delegate protocols.

Comment: Sure, but I was more interested in the specific advantages of the pattern, rather than just following that pattern for the sake of conformity. Not that I think conformity is bad thing, but when you don't understand the reasoning behind it, that just encourages cargo cult programming.

Comment: I just saw your respond thanks for this great explanation. You are right I'm quite new programmer on objective C and in oop too but I'm trying to learn. So to be sure that I understood this right you are saying that is more better to not use AppDelegate as the main class of the app. And I should create new classes and make connections between them in AppDelegate. And also I shouldn't get an object from a class I should send it. This sounds like segues in iPhone developing right? it's look like the same principle only that in OSx you don't have segues.

Comment: Segues was an example of sending references up to object that you create and communicating downwards to parents using delegatation and protocols. The principle of that is what is important, not the segues.